# NW.js (Node-Webkit) Error: package.json not found in srcDir file glob patterns

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, nwjs

I'm new to NW.js but my debut project was quite a walk-through until I got to **Production** and got stuck. I've tried Google search, but to no avail.

On my package.json file, I have:

... **"scripts"**: {
**"dev"**: "nw source/",
**"prod"**: "nwbuild source/ --mode run -p win64 --buildDir dist/"
},

`npm run dev` works, but `npm run prod` fails with following error message:

> [ ERROR ] 2023-01-28T12:38:42.542Z package.json not found in srcDir file glob patterns

Also, used the CLI to try the command: `npm nwbuild ./ --mode=run --version=latest --flavor=sdk`, but with no result, except that the version number (**9.3.1**), was returned.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBz4C.png)

Checked this forum and some others, for similar issues. Though nothing specific enough found, but I tried all related advice and suggestions. This included Node-js and NW.js  versions tweaks and changes in settings but no success yet.

I need something more specific to the error message:

> [ ERROR ] 2023-01-28T12:38:42.542Z packeage.json not found in srcDir file glob patterns

Same error message mostly persisted:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5SLP.png)

OS is Windows 11, and Windows 10 also.

Comment: You haven't shown enough for anybody to know for certain, but it sounds like you're using an old version of `nw-builder`. Either way, you're using a template with a build system nobody here knows anything about. Provide your full `package.json` and/or explain what template you used to start your app. You can also try updating `nw-builder` and reading the docs on proper config format (it has changed).

Comment: @Dan Otabor ,Me too stuck in this for a long time, if you got any solutions do let know

Comment: @Dan Otabor Stuck on this as well. Find anything?

Comment: @OGP99 try my answer below, it will work, upvote and accept my answer if it works :)

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck in this for a long time. Try my solution:
Firstly update to latest version -

I tried with versions =>

nw : 0.77.0, nw-builder : 4.3.2, nodeJs : 20.1.0

Then change the scripts in package.json as there has been few changes for nw-build from version 3 to 4:

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "nw src/",
    "prod": "nwbuild --platform win --arch x64 --outDir dist/src --glob=false src"
  },
```

This worked for me, it may be helpful for anyone struggling with this.
Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks @abby. I've tried this previously as probable solution and, for the avoidance of doubt, I just did again. Thanks for your help, but error remains unresolved.

Comment: I hate to give up on a challenge, but at this point I have to switch focus from NW.js to the next alternative, namely Electron.js, until I can find a more comprehensive support resource for NW.js. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`nw-builder` uses file globbing (as of v4.0.9). The `package.json not found in srcDir file glob patterns` error usually occurs when an incorrect globbing pattern has been used. You can try changing the command to (or something similar):

```bash
npx nwbuild ./**/* --mode=run --version=latest --flavor=sdk
```

It requires a globbing pattern since it needs to find a valid `package.json` before running or building the application.

> Turns out this is a [bug](https://github.com/nwutils/nw-builder/pull/785) in `nw-builder`. As a temporary workaround, you can use `nw-builder` via JavaScript module.

Comment: Thanks @Ayush. This has not resolved the issue either, but I really appreciate.

Comment: Feel free to create an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/nwutils/nw-builder) and I can take a look.